# Single quotation (") in string with C# in cmd command

Tags: c#, string

I try to execute a command in cmd but I have problem with space in command. I know that this problem, solved with quotation around part that contains space. I try this:

```
string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Process cmdexe = new Process();
string filename="D:\\new doc.pdf";
cmdexe.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
string command = string.Format("\"{0}\\pdftotext.exe\" -enc UTF-8 \"{1}\" \"{2}\\123.txt\"", currentDirectory, fileName, currentDirectory);
cmdexe.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c " + command;
 cmdexe.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
cmdexe.Start();
cmdexe.Close();
```

for example output should be: `"D:\folder item\pdftotext.exe" -enc UTF-8 "D:\\new doc.pdf" "D:\\123.txt"`. this is right but cmd is not work.
please help me to find solution.

Comment: "this is right but cmd is not work." - please clarify how it isn't working.

Comment: You're repeating yourself.  @Dai is asking whether you're getting an error and what that error is.  "not work" doesn't tell us anything.... at all.

Comment: sorry. I try convert pdf to text with pdftotext app. there is no error but pdf dont convert to text means cmd isnt work with this command.

Comment: If you're getting no errors, then it has nothing to do with your command line formatting, as you've got that part right, as it appears.  If that was the problem, you'd get something along the lines of "... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Thanks @B. K. I find the problem. in a string for cmd command just should use one(\" \") for part of string and I have three. for solve my problem first copy the pdftotext to Temp then use it. I use quotation just for filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immediately after `cmdexe.Start()`, you use `cmdexe.Close()`, without waiting for the process to finish.

See here for an example on how to monitor and wait for the process to finish:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(v=vs.110).aspx

It may be worthwhile to place the Process creation in a `using` block so you don't have to call `.Close()`, but you will need to test whether you have to wait for the process to complete anyway.

Comment: It's not work with your solution. I think the problem is command.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process) for several working examples, in particular the "C# program that runs EXE" example.